# Ubuntu 18.04, Scripts not starting at boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, scripts, python, startup

I have two scripts that need to run at start up. Both are Python scripts and have a sleep 60; command to allow the OS to fully boot before they start running.

What's odd is I have an identical machine running the same scripts and they start no problem at boot. I can't find any difference between the systems.

Notes:

1. When I run the scripts straight from the command line they work no problem and yield the correct results.
2. All scripts are stored in my `/home/username/main_folder/startup_scripts_folder` directory.

Any ideas why they aren't running from the startup applications?